# Writing Parsed Data to CSV with rows/columns

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I am writing a code in Python and would like to have some advice on how to write them to a csv file with a specific format. 
**Data:**

```
Dataset1: 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20
Dataset2: 6,16
```

**Desired Output in CSV File:**

```
                  Value1   Value2   Value3   Value4   Value5
                  2        4        6        8        10 
Average Value: 6  
                  12       14       16       18       20
Average Value: 16
```

Code for attempt:

```
import csv  
with open(OutFile, 'wb') as csv_file:
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
for row in data1:
    for row2 in data2:
        writer.writerow(row)
        writer.writerow(row2)
```

Comment: Please don't "bump" just to try to get attention. Someone will see your question and help if they can. It's always better if you include a tag for the language you're using, so that people who are familiar with that language can see the question sooner. I've added it for you.

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid CSV. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: I agree this is a poor approach to storing or presenting data, and is not CSV (or TSV) by any definition. Make a first or last column to store the averages?

Comment: How would we store a piece of data from a list into one cell in an excel .csv file?